# Joining two queries to display in the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries that display independently.

```
SELECT 'New Orders'    AS 'Type', @new_customers    AS 'Total', CONCAT(ROUND((@new_customers    / @total_purchases) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage';
SELECT 'Repeat Orders' AS 'Type', @repeat_customers AS 'Total', CONCAT(ROUND((@repeat_customers / @total_purchases) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage';
```

I would like to list them together so the show as such

```
+---------------+-------+------------+
| Type          | Total | Percentage |
+---------------+-------+------------+
| New Orders    |     4 | 11.4%      |
| Repeat Orders |     4 | 11.4%      |
+---------------+-------+------------+
```

Here are the variables and view

```
## SQL Variables
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email) FROM sales_flat_order INTO @new_customers;
SELECT COUNT(customer_email) FROM view_orders WHERE total_orders > 1 INTO @repeat_customers;

## VIEW Customer total orders
CREATE VIEW foodhub_magento.v_orders AS
    SELECT
        customer_email, COUNT(*) AS total_orders
    FROM
        foodhubsales_flat_order
    GROUP BY
        customer_email
    HAVING
        COUNT(customer_email) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `union all` operator:

```
SELECT 'New Orders'    AS 'Type', @new_customers    AS 'Total', CONCAT(ROUND((@new_customers    / @total_purchases) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Repeat Orders' AS 'Type', @repeat_customers AS 'Total', CONCAT(ROUND((@repeat_customers / @total_purchases) * 100, 1), '%') AS 'Percentage';
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response. Plus 1 and waiting for the timer to give up to accept.